# How can i restore deleted CoreGraphics framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, libraries

How can I restore deleted framework?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

click on your project target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

and click on (+) symbol , tape CoreGraphics on search text field

**EDIT:** I suggest you to reinstall Xcode because there are no way to download it , or if you have another machine with the same version of Xcode you can copy it from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Comment: Framework has been moved to Trash and deleted... thats why color is red

Comment: I suggest you to reinstall Xcode because there are no way to download it , or if you have another machine with the same version of Xcode you can copy it from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Comment: Found the link: https://github.com/sassembla/TransitRepository/tree/master/CoreGraphics.framework
Can I use this library?

Comment: 3 years ago, it seem very old

Comment: Hi Evgeny Fedin, have you fixe this issue ?

Comment: Yes, i did - downloaded library from github (link above)